# Re-using XSD complexType

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD:

```
<element name="OrderElement" type="tns:OrderType"></element>

<complexType name="OrderType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="Name" type="tns:NameType"></element>
        <element name="Address" type="tns:AddressType"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="NameType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="FirstName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="string">
        </element>
        <element name="Surname" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="string">
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="AddressType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="AddressLine1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
            type="string">
        </element>
        <element name="AddressLine2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
            type="string">
        </element>
        <element name="Country" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
            type="tns:CountriesDeliveryType">
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="CountriesDeliveryType">
    <choice minOccurs="1">
        <element name="USA" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
        <element name="Brazil" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
        <element name="China" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

What I want to do is have a complex type so that I can re-use the countries throughout the code. The problem I am having is that within the XML it validates when I remove the country:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:OrderElement xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema NewXMLSchema.xsd ">
  <tns:Name>
    <tns:FirstName>tns:FirstName</tns:FirstName>
    <tns:Surname>tns:Surname</tns:Surname>
  </tns:Name>
  <tns:Address>
    <tns:AddressLine1>tns:AddressLine1</tns:AddressLine1>
    <tns:AddressLine2>tns:AddressLine2</tns:AddressLine2>
    <tns:Country>
      <tns:USA>tns:USA</tns:USA>
    </tns:Country>
  </tns:Address>
</tns:OrderElement>
```

i.e. If I remove the
`<tns:USA>tns:USA</tns:USA>`
it still validates.

I've been looking into this for ages but haven't come across a solution. It's probably something simple but I can't seem to work it out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in your `minOccurs="0"`. All of the countries can be not set at the same time due to this. Fix would look like

```
<complexType name="CountriesDeliveryType">
    <choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3">
        <element name="USA" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
        <element name="Brazil" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
        <element name="China" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

Though, there still could be two `<USA>` elements.

Comment: As you said duplicating <USA> elements is the only problem now. If I find an answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: In case you don't have a very big list of countries, you can enumerate all the possible cases. Let's write sequence as comma, choice as bar, `minoccurs="0"` as question sign. Then you need `(usa, (brazil? china? | china? brazil?)) | (brazil, (usa? china? | china? usa?)) | (china, (brazil? usa? | usa? brazil?))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I, however, have over 15 countries that I need so that would be quite tedious. I'll look into it more and see if I come across anything.

Comment: It strikes me as pretty odd to use country names as element names. I would expect to see `<country>USA<country>` rather than `<USA>USA</USA>`.